# Refer enum inside an enum

Tags: java, enums

If,

```
enum Things{
   UNIQUE_THING,
   NON_UNIQUE_THINGS; // Need to specify what n0n-unique things as a separate enum
}

enum NonUniqueThings {
   THING_1,
   THING_2;
}
```

Is there any way to refer just one enum `Things` and specify the behavior of `NonUniqueThings` in it? What I meant, can caller call like -

```
Things.UNIQUE_THING
```

or

```
Things.NON_UNIQUE_THING.THING_1
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 3):

You can introduce a nullable parameter for `Things` that will hold some `NonUniqueThings` value. Of course, you have to then provide a constructor for `Things` plus a getter for the param, in order to fetch the `NonUniqueThings` value.

Note that I'm assuming that `UNIQUE_THING` will not be bound to some `NonUniqueThing` and that's why it's instantiated with `null` as a parameter.

```
enum Things{
   UNIQUE_THING(null),
   NON_UNIQUE_THINGS(NonUniqueThings.THING_1);

   NonUniqueThings param;

   Things(NonUniqueThings param) {
       this.param = param;
   }

   public NonUniqueThing getNonUniqueThing() {
       return param;
   }
}
```

Then, you can fetch the `NonUniqueThings` value, bound to each of the `Things` values, like this:

```
NonUniqueThings nonUniqueThing = Things.NON_UNIQUE_THING.getNonUniqueThing();
```

Comment: Aren't you hard-coding THING_1 in line 3rd, what if user want to call Things.NON_UNIQUE_THING.THING_2. I'm new to Java, and trying the THING_2 for your solution.

Comment: Yes, I am. But that's just the nature of enum values in Java. If you need to support multiple nested values, you can change the type of the `param` to  array (`NonUniqueThings[]`) and then, when defining `NON_UNIQUE_THINGS` to do `NON_UNIQUE_THINGS({NonUniqueThings.FIRST, NonUniqueThings.SECOND})`.

Comment: Ok, I just need one NonUniqueThing at a time. Thanks.

Comment: Just a question in mind, how can the caller specify NON_UNIQUE_THINGS(NonUniqueThings.THING_2), or NON_UNIQUE_THINGS(NonUniqueThings.THING_1), in two different scenarios, for enumThings? Do we need a setter then? Can't we do something like Thing..NON_UNIQUE_THING.Thing_2, and it will set the value in constructor?

Comment: A setter will do fine.

Comment: The calls like Things.UNIQUE_THING.setNonUniqueThings(NonUniqueThings), could happen here, and then Things.UNIQUE_THING.getNonUniqueThings() is an issue, even we add a null check in getter.

Comment: I use this technique all the time, and like to avoid getters making the fields **public final** and accessing them directly.

Answer (score 2):

something like this? No realy nice solution it should work.

```
enum Things {
        UNIQUE_THING,
        NON_UNIQUE_THING(
            NonUniqueThings.A,
            NonUniqueThings.C);

    public final Child[] childs;

    private Things() {
        this.childs = null;
    }

    private Things(Child... childs) {
        this.childs = childs;
    }
}

interface Child {
    //
}

enum NonUniqueThings implements Child {
    A,
    B,
    C;
}
```

Comment: That's a nice solution, too.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go (if I've understood your need correctly):

```
public enum Things {
    UNIQUE_THING, NON_UNIQUE_THINGS;

    public enum NonUniqueThings {
        THING_1, THING_2;
    }
}
```

Could be accessed like:

```
Things.NonUniqueThings.THING_1
```

Comment: What is NON_UNIQUE_THINGS (enum element) is for then, if there is a separate enum for NonUniueThings?

Comment: I thought that you would like to access NonUniqueThings in a nested fashion. In case you mean that second selection options are dependent on the first ones then you have to go with kocko's solution.